# html & javascript enter button redirects to error page - otherwise duplicates text to chat (only when enter is pressed)

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I click on the enter button, it seems the page either shows me

> Bad Request
> Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.

or rarely if enter is pressed it creates duplicates each chat by itself and adds it to the div

I have removed the key event of enter but for some odd reason the enter function still works, I presume this is due to bootstrap but im not too certain.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 500px">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/stylesheet.css') }}">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="https://www.unpkg.com/spltjs@1.1.0"></script>
    <script src="https://releases.jquery.com/git/jquery-git.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/5.0.2/typeit.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <!-- Navbar content -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" style="height:34px">click me</button>
      <p style="color:white; font-family: Lexend;font-size: 15px;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;">AI for a healthier you</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" style="height:34px">click me</button>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <center>
      
        <div class="container" style="background-color:white ;  border-radius: 20px;height:80%;-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 79px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 79px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);box-shadow: 10px 10px 79px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);">
          <p style="color:black" id="hello"></p>
          <form method="post">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...." aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="userid" id="textinput">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" value="hello world" id="button">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      
    </center>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", insertText);
      // CREATES A DIV AND SENDS THE USERS TEXT
      function insertText() {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        let usertext = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
        const usertext2 = 'Patient: ' + usertext;
        let text = document.createTextNode(usertext2);
        div.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById("hello").appendChild(div);
        /////////////// submit JSON TO APP
        var json_entry = usertext
        fetch('/dashboard', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            user_text: json_entry
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
        let apiData;
        fetch('/dashboard/api').then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
          apiData = data;
          let div = document.createElement('div');
          let robot_reply = document.createTextNode(apiData);
          div.appendChild(robot_reply);
          document.getElementById("hello").appendChild(div);
        });
        ////// ENTER BUTTON ////
        ///////////////////////
        /////////////////////// allows the ability to hit the enter button 
        var input = document.getElementById("textinput");
        
      }
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit enter, it triggers the `submit` event on the `<form>`, which will cause a page refresh. This is basically baked in browser functionality. Any enter keypress in a field inside a `<form>` tag, causes a form submission. If that form submission is not handled, it will attempt to `POST` the form to the current URL.

You need to attach everything to the `submit` event on the `<form>`, not the button click. And you also need to call `e.preventDefault` to prevent the browsers default form action handling.

Additionally, you need `type="submit"` on the button so the click on that button also submits the form.

Using form submit event is also better for accessibility. It means users can press enter in a field or click the button, and it will be handled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 500px">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/stylesheet.css') }}">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="https://www.unpkg.com/spltjs@1.1.0"></script>
    <script src="https://releases.jquery.com/git/jquery-git.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/5.0.2/typeit.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <!-- Navbar content -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" style="height:34px">click me</button>
      <p style="color:white; font-family: Lexend;font-size: 15px;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;">AI for a healthier you</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" style="height:34px">click me</button>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <center>
      
        <div class="container" style="background-color:white ;  border-radius: 20px;height:80%;-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 79px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 79px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);box-shadow: 10px 10px 79px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);">
          <p style="color:black" id="hello"></p>
          <form method="post" id="form">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...." aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="userid" id="textinput">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" value="hello world" id="button">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      
    </center>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", insertText);
      // CREATES A DIV AND SENDS THE USERS TEXT
      function insertText(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        let usertext = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
        const usertext2 = 'Patient: ' + usertext;
        let text = document.createTextNode(usertext2);
        div.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById("hello").appendChild(div);
        /////////////// submit JSON TO APP
        var json_entry = usertext
        fetch('/dashboard', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            user_text: json_entry
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
        let apiData;
        fetch('/dashboard/api').then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
          apiData = data;
          let div = document.createElement('div');
          let robot_reply = document.createTextNode(apiData);
          div.appendChild(robot_reply);
          document.getElementById("hello").appendChild(div);
        });
        ////// ENTER BUTTON ////
        ///////////////////////
        /////////////////////// allows the ability to hit the enter button 
        var input = document.getElementById("textinput");
        
      }
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```